# Expanding divs with buttons, revealing more information hidden in the div

Tags: jquery, css

Hey I'm having a small problem regarding showing/hiding elements within a div.

I have a display image of a book nested inside a div with two buttons. One button called [subscription] and another button called [receipt].

When pressing the [subscription]-button, the div expands and will show additional infomations like the expiration date. When pressing the [receipt]-button, the div expands even more, and will now show a complete receipt including logo, text, prices etc.

THIS ALL WORKS VERY FINE, BUT ...

When I have more than one 'book' (each book in its own div called [.mybooks-container]), all the books divs are expanded, and not just the one I actually am clicking on. So for example when clicking the [receipt]-button, all books are showing the complete receipt including logo, text, prices etc. at the same time, and not just the one I clicked.

If anyone please could point me in the right direction, I would be very grateful …

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.subscription').css('display', 'none');
$('.button.red').click(function(){
$(".mybooks-container").height(135)
$('.receipt').css('display', 'none');
$('.subscription').toggle();
if($('.subscription').is(':visible')) {
    $(this).val('Abonnement');
    $(".mybooks-container").height(260)
} else {
    $(this).val('Abonnement');
}
});
$('.receipt').css('display', 'none');
$('.button.orange').click(function(){
    $(".mybooks-container").height(135)
    $('.subscription').css('display', 'none');
            $('.receipt').toggle();
                if($('.receipt').is(':visible')) {
    $(this).val('Luk kvitteringen');
    $(".mybooks-container").height(540)
} else {
    $(this).val('Kvittering');
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

When the `.button.orange` click event is handled, you should use something like: `$(this).parent(".mybooks-container").find(".receipt").toggle();` * - Since I can't see your HTML, I cannot guarantee this selector will work, but hopefully you will understand the principle

What you're doing at the moment is toggling all elements with a specific class - of which you have many, which is why they all hide.

If you find the specific div that contains the exact button you clicked, you can show and hide the correct items, rather than all of them.

You also have the option of restructuring your HTML to give the elements IDs, which makes writing specific jQuery selectors easier, but I have used your existing structure for the purposes of an immediate answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @SpaceBison, this will still expand all the divs of the 'books', but would only show the receipt from the book clicked.

I was thinking something regarding the event.stopPropagation, but I can't figure it out … hmm

Comment: Adopt the same process for any/all DIVs that you wish to show or hide - this example is just for receipts, yes, but it will expand to the other areas just as easily.